# QtCreator dereference pointers in debugger (using libraries)

Tags: c++, debugging, qt-creator

I'm working in Qt Creator 2.4.1 on Kubuntu 12.04. I'm using the [GDAL/OGR](http://gdal.org/ogr/index.html) library in my project (not sources).

When I use the debugger in the "Locals and Expressions" window, I can only see addresses of GDAL/OGR objects not their fields.

Of course the option "Dereference Pointer Automatically" is checked. When using my own objects (class definitions are in sources) and creating pointers to them, I can see all the details.

Is it possible to see library objects states?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to see those objects, provided that the debug symbols of those libraries are available.